# plasmashell and login window not starting with nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kde, nvidia-prime

Hello i have kubutnu 21.04 with kernel version 5.11.0-18-generic.

I installed the latest nvidia driver and when i bootup the system i get a black screen then i went to tty 3 and tried to start plasmashell from there and i got this output:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display qt.qpa.plugin: could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem."
```

I the reinstalled xcb and it din't fix it. Then i changed the graphics to intel with sudo prime-select intel and restarted, the problem was gone.

So my question is how cani fix this so i can use my nvidia mx450 card instead of the intel card?

Thanks in advance!

Kde plasma version: 5.21.4; Kde frameworks version: 5.80.0; Qt version: 5.25.2

Update: when i use the x.org nouveau driver it displays that i have the nouveau driver but when i select the nvidia 465 driver cpu-x says that the nvidia card does not have a driver. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pnbh.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JE5X.png

Edit: I installed the driver from the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

inxi -F:

````
System
  Host: vidakov-super-komp Kernel: 5.11.0-18-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.21.4 Distro: Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Pavilion Laptop 15-eg0xxx 
  v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: <superuser required> 
  Mobo: HP model: 8850 v: 34.27 serial: <superuser required> 
  UEFI: Insyde v: F.11 date: 01/15/2021 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 19.2 Wh condition: 41.9/41.9 Wh (100%) 
CPU:
  Info: Quad Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 bits: 64 
  type: MT MCP L2 cache: 12 MiB 
  Speed: 1200 MHz min/max: 400/4700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1200 
  2: 1200 3: 1201 4: 1201 5: 1295 6: 1370 7: 1346 8: 1230 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 
  v: kernel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce MX450] driver: N/A 
  Device-3: Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP Wide Vision HD Camera 
  type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting 
  unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.1 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio driver: sof-audio-pci 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-18-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
  driver: rtw_8822ce 
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: 64:6c:80:26:38:43 
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb 
  Report: ID: hci0 state: down address: 64:6C:80:26:38:44 
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller 
  driver: vmd 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 117.46 GiB (24.6%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Intel model: SSDPEKNW512G8H 
  size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 117.41 GiB (25.1%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 45.4 MiB (8.9%) fs: vfat 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 221 Uptime: 11m Memory: 15.4 GiB used: 1.98 GiB (12.8%) 
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.01```
````

Comment: Just disable Secure Boot in UEFI and try again.

Answer (score 0):

`Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce MX450] driver: N/A`

You did not install the driver properly. Nvidia site says that [this](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/175875/en-us) is the one for your card.

Comment: i have tried an this is what i got. https://imgur.com/a/Q59yFzq

Comment: @SuperVidak64 did you reboot after installation?